# How to (theoretically) print all possible double precision numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

For a little personal research project I want to generate a string list of all possible values a double precision floating point number can have.

I've found the "r" formatting option, which guarantees that the string can be parsed back into the exact same bit representation:

```
string s = myDouble.ToString("r");
```

But how to generate all possible bit combinations? Preferably ordered by value.

Maybe using the `unchecked` keyword somehow?

```
unchecked
{
    //for all long values
    myDouble[i] = myLong++;
}
```

Disclaimer: It's more a theoretical question, I am not going to read all the numbers... :)

Comment: theres a lot of them...

Comment: Just do a quick bit of math before you start here - there are 52 bits in the mantissa part of a `double`. That means that, for a *single* value of the exponent (there are 2048 of them, but some have special meanings) and the sign bit, there are 4503599627370496 possible values.

Comment: yes, a whole lot! don't worry about storage and ram, I'll figure that out later... It's more a theoretical question I have.

Comment: And from that number - you need to be generating more than 140 million of these *per second* in order to exhaust *one* exponent value in a year.

Comment: But it's the kind of theoretical question (like "how do I enumerate all of the possible values of a long?") that, once you find yourself asking it, you realize that whatever it was you were planning to do, you need to stop and tackle the overall problem in a different way. It doesn't matter if you were planning to read this list or just pass it to another function/program - you're going to run out of time (or you need massive amounts of parallelism that aren't exploitable from C#)

Comment: I recommend that you wait 18 month, then the generation of the numbers will be twice as fast because the computers will be twice as fast by that time - according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes i see that now, so let's reduce the question to: how to generate all possible bit combinations without duplicate values.

Answer (score 3):

using unsafe code:

```
ulong i = 0; //long is 64 bit, like double
unsafe
{
    double* d = (double*)&i;
    for(;i<ulong.MaxValue;i++)
        Console.WriteLine(*d);
}
```

Comment: That makes for a lot of duplicate numbers, as there are several ways of expressing the same value as different bit patterns...

Comment: @Guffa, do you have an idea how to sort them out?

Answer (score 3):

You can start with all possible values 0 <= x < 1. You can create those by having zero for exponent and use different values for the mantissa.

The mantissa is stored in 52 bits of the 64 bits that make a double precision number, so that makes for 2 ^ 52 = 4503599627370496 different numbers between 0 and 1.

From the [description of the decimal format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) you can figure out how the bit pattern (eight bytes) should be for those numbers, then you can use the [`BitConverter.ToDouble` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the conversion.

Then you can set the first bit to make the negative version of all those numbers.

All those numbers are unique, beyond that you will start getting duplicate values because there are several ways to express the same value when the exponent is non-zero. For each new non-zero exponent you would get the value that were not possible to express with the previously used expontents.

The values between 0 and 1 will however keep you busy for the forseeable future, so you can just start with those.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable in safe code: Create a bit string. Convert that to a double. Output. Increment. Repeat.... A LOT.

```
string bstr = "01010101010101010101010101010101"; // this is 32 instead of 64, adjust as needed
long v = 0;
for (int i = bstr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) v = (v << 1) + (bstr[i] - '0');
double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(BitConverter.GetBytes(v), 0);
```

// increment bstr and loop

Comment: Why not just increment the long?

Comment: Not sure you can use the long increment technique without going unsafe, since it involves reassigning a reference from a long to a double. The above conversion should be possible without going unsafe. Some people/organizations may have strong feelings about unsafe code.

Comment: what do you think this does: `BitConverter.ToDouble(BitConverter.GetBytes(v), 0);` it's `long` to `double` - safe.

Comment: I'm just saying drop the string. and instead of `// increment bstr and loop` `v++` and loop.